# Sum of features from one layer to another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve, aggregation

I have two different shapefiles and I work in Arcmap. This is what I have:

[image: Shapefile containing smaller areas]

[image: Shapefile containing larger areas]

The areas in picture 1 are smaller areas and the areas in picture 2 are in an aggregated form. File 1 contains number of residents in the years 2000, 2005, 2010 and 2015. What I need is to sum the number of residents by year to know how many people are living in the larger areas. So, lets say 4 of the smaller areas make out for 1 of the bigger ones. I need to sum the number of residents from the 4 areas to know the number of residents in the 1 large one. The strange thing is; I know I've done this with the dissolve-tool before but I simply cannot remember what I'm doing wrong right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the aggregated file Join and Spatial Relates> Join. 
Then click 'Join Data from another layer based on spatial location. You can choose the option to sum the values at point 2.